# Tensorflow 2 TypeError: Expected int32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Greater', got 1e-12 of type 'float' instead

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, named-entity-recognition

I am performing NER in TensorFlow 2, but when I perform F1Score calculation through Tensorflwo_Addons it keeps giving me this error

`TypeError: Expected int32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Greater', got 1e-12 of type 'float' instead. Error: Expected int32, got 1e-12 of type 'float' instead.`

The function that is producing this error is > model_fn

The first part of code for data preparation

```
__author__ = "Guillaume Genthial"

import functools
import json
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import sys

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_addons as tf_ad
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

# DiRECTORY PATH
DATADIR = '/content/drive/My Drive/7th Semester/FYP Related Stuff /data/example'

# Logging
Path('results').mkdir(exist_ok=True)
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(logging.INFO) # INFO --> Type of message like error, warning, etc
handlers = [
    logging.FileHandler('results/main.log'),
    logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
]
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').handlers = handlers


# parse function
def parse_fn(line_words, line_tags):
    # Encode in Bytes for TF
    words = [word.encode() for word in line_words.strip().split()]
    tags = [tag.encode() for tag in line_tags.strip().split()]
    assert len(words) == len(tags), "Words and tags lengths don't match" # Returns assertion error
    return (words, len(words)), tags

# Data Generator function
def generator_fn(words, tags):
    with Path(words).open('r') as file_words, Path(tags).open('r') as file_tags:
        for line_words, line_tags in zip(file_words, file_tags):
            yield parse_fn(line_words, line_tags) # yield: to return sth from function without stoping the function and exe starts from last yeild stat

# Input Function 
def input_fn(words, tags, params=None, shuffle_and_repeat=False):
    params = params if params is not None else {}
    shapes = ((tf.TensorShape([None]), tf.TensorShape(())), tf.TensorShape([None])) 
    types = ((tf.string, tf.int32), tf.string) # data types fro tensor
    defaults = (('<pad>', 0), 'O') # padding in case of mismatched length

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        functools.partial(generator_fn, words, tags),
        output_shapes=shapes, output_types=types)

    if shuffle_and_repeat:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(params['buffer']).repeat(params['epochs'])

    dataset = (dataset
               .padded_batch(params.get('batch_size', 20), shapes, defaults)
               .prefetch(1))
    return dataset
```

Model function

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    # For serving, features are a bit different
    
    if isinstance(features, dict):
      # if not a tensor
      features = features['words'], features['nwords']
      
    dropout = params['dropout']
    words, nwords = features # words and number of words
    
    training = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    vocab_words = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(
        tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer( 
            params['words'], 
            key_dtype=tf.string, key_index=tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.WHOLE_LINE,
            value_dtype=tf.int64, value_index=tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.LINE_NUMBER,
            delimiter="\n" ),
        num_oov_buckets=params['num_oov_buckets'])
    
    with Path(params['tags']).open() as f:
        indices = [idx for idx, tag in enumerate(f) if tag.strip() != 'O']
        num_tags = len(indices) + 1 # number of tags in tag file

    # Word Embeddings
    word_ids = vocab_words.lookup(words)
    
    glove = np.load(params['glove'])['embeddings']  # np.array
    variable = np.vstack([glove, [[0.]*params['dim']]])
    shape = variable.shape

    # getting embeddings
    variable = tf.Variable(variable, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
    embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(variable, word_ids)


    # LSTM
    dropout_lstm = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout)
    embeddings = dropout_lstm(embeddings, training=training)
    layer_fw = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(params['lstm_size'], return_sequences=True)
    layer_bw = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(params['lstm_size'], go_backwards=True)
    bilstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(layer_fw)
    output = bilstm(embeddings)

    dropout_crf = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout)
    output = dropout_crf(output)

    dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_tags)

    logits = dense_layer(output)

    initial_val = np.zeros((num_tags,num_tags))# [[1.,1.,1.,1.],[1.,1.,1.,1.],[1.,1.,1.,1.],[1.,1.,1.,1.]]
    # crf_params = tf.Variable(initial_value=initial_val ,name="crf",shape=[num_tags,num_tags], dtype=tf.float32)
    crf_params = tf.convert_to_tensor(initial_val,dtype=tf.float32)

    pred_ids, _ = tf_ad.text.crf_decode(logits,crf_params, nwords)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        # Predictions
        reverse_vocab_tags = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(
            tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer( 
              params['tags'], 
              key_dtype=tf.int64, key_index=tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.LINE_NUMBER,
              value_dtype=tf.string, value_index=tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.WHOLE_LINE,
              delimiter="\n" 
              ),
              num_oov_buckets=params['num_oov_buckets']
            )
        pred_strings = reverse_vocab_tags.lookup(tf.to_int64(pred_ids))
        predictions = {
            'pred_ids': pred_ids,
            'tags': pred_strings
        }
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)
    else:
        # Loss
        vocab_tags = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(
            tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer( 
                params['tags'], 
                key_dtype=tf.string, key_index=tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.WHOLE_LINE,
                value_dtype=tf.int64, value_index=tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.LINE_NUMBER,
                delimiter="\n" 
                ),
                num_oov_buckets=params['num_oov_buckets']
            )
        tags = vocab_tags.lookup(labels)
        log_likelihood, _ = tf_ad.text.crf.crf_log_likelihood(
            logits, tags, nwords, crf_params)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(-log_likelihood)
        print("\nloss of error",loss,"\n")

        # Metrics
        weights = tf.sequence_mask(nwords)

        #Accuracy
        acc_layer = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
        acc_layer.update_state(tags, pred_ids, weights)
        acc = acc_layer

        #Precision
        pre_layer = tf.keras.metrics.Precision(top_k=num_tags)
        pre_layer.update_state(tags, pred_ids, weights)
        pre = pre_layer

        #Recall
        rec_layer = tf.keras.metrics.Recall(top_k=num_tags)
        rec_layer.update_state(tags, pred_ids, weights)
        rec = rec_layer

        print(tf.keras.backend.cast(tags, dtype="int32"))

        # f1 Score
        f1_layer = tf_ad.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=num_tags, average="weighted")
        f1_layer.update_state(tf.keras.backend.cast(tags, dtype="int32"), tf.keras.backend.cast(pred_ids, dtype="int32"), weights)
        f1_score = f1_layer

        metrics = {
            'acc': acc,
            'precision': pre,
            'recall': rec,
            'f1_score': f1_score,
        }

      
        # for metric_name, op in metrics.items():
        #     print(f"\nThe metric_name is:{metric_name} and op is:{op}\n")
        #     ret = tf.summary.scalar(metric_name, op.result())
        #     print(ret)


        def loss_fn():
          loss = tf.reduce_mean(-log_likelihood)
          return loss

        print("\nloss function\n",metrics)

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)
        elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            train_op = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(
                loss)
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

Main.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Params
    params = {
        'dim': 300,
        'dropout': 0.5,
        'num_oov_buckets': 1,
        'epochs': 25,
        'batch_size': 20,
        'buffer': 15000,
        'lstm_size': 100,
        'words': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.words.txt')),
        'chars': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.chars.txt')),
        'tags': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.tags.txt')),
        'glove': str(Path(DATADIR, 'glove.npz'))
    }
    with Path('results/params.json').open('w') as f:
        json.dump(params, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

    def fwords(name):
        return str(Path(DATADIR, '{}.words.txt'.format(name)))

    def ftags(name):
        return str(Path(DATADIR, '{}.tags.txt'.format(name)))

    # Estimator, train and evaluate
    train_inpf = functools.partial(input_fn, fwords('train'), ftags('train'),
                                   params, shuffle_and_repeat=True)
    eval_inpf = functools.partial(input_fn, fwords('testa'), ftags('testa'))

    cfg = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=120)
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn, 'results/model', cfg, params)
    Path(estimator.eval_dir()).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    # hook is used to stop and then run a pspecific func or piece of code after specific time
    hook = tf.estimator.experimental.stop_if_no_increase_hook(
        estimator, 'f1', 500, min_steps=8000, run_every_secs=120)
    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_inpf, hooks=[hook])
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_inpf, throttle_secs=120)
    tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)

    # Write predictions to file
    def write_predictions(name):
        Path('results/score').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        with Path('results/score/{}.preds.txt'.format(name)).open('wb') as f:
            test_inpf = functools.partial(input_fn, fwords(name), ftags(name))
            golds_gen = generator_fn(fwords(name), ftags(name))
            preds_gen = estimator.predict(test_inpf)
            for golds, preds in zip(golds_gen, preds_gen):
                ((words, _), tags) = golds
                for word, tag, tag_pred in zip(words, tags, preds['tags']):
                    f.write(b' '.join([word, tag, tag_pred]) + b'\n')
                f.write(b'\n')

    for name in ['train', 'testa', 'testb']:
        write_predictions(name)
```

Another that is causing trouble is this:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [predictions must be <= 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (Cast_6:0) = ] [[3 3 3...]...] [y (Cast_9/x:0) = ] [1]
     [[{{node Assert}}]]
```

This happens when I comment out f1score calculation and comment it out in metrics dict

Please help out I am totally stuck with it. Actually, I am converting TF 1 code to TF2 the code that was in TF 1 was working, but when I made the necessary changes to run it in TF2 it started giving these errors

Also, I was trying to use `tf.keras.optimiser.Adam()`.minimize() but it gave error `No gradients provided for any of the variable` I use `loss_fn` for loss of `minimize` and `tv` for trainable_variables

```
def loss_fn():
   return loss = tf.reduce_mean(-log_likelihood)
```

`tv = dense_layer.trainable_weights + bilst.trainable_weights`

I am seriously stuck, I have tried all the GitHub solutions that were posted regarding similar problems, but nothing worked.

Specifications of code:

- Tensorflow 2
- GloVe for emdeddings

Comment: I think this is a bug results from tf-add-on f1 score. I have the same issue.         `y_pred = tf.logical_and(y_pred >= threshold, tf.abs(y_pred) > 1e-12)` from `tensorflow_addons/metrics/f_scores.py`

Comment: Opened a github issue. https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2526#issue-946094242